# Create Balance Transfer using a Proxy

Tags: polkadot, python, proxy

I am trying to initiate a `balance transfer call` using a proxy with the '`Any`' type. I'm using the `Python API`, which allows me to create and submit the transaction successfully. However, it fails (https://westend.subscan.io/extrinsic/17455468-2). I am able to create the transaction using a wallet for the wallets.

```
# Compose the transfer call using the balances module
    transfer_call = substrate.compose_call(
        call_module='Balances',
        call_function='transfer',
        call_params={
            'dest': recipient_address,
            'value': transfer_amount,
        },
    )

    # Compose the proxy call to execute the transfer via the proxy
    proxy_call = substrate.compose_call(
        call_module='Proxy',
        call_function='proxy',
        call_params={
            'real': proxy_account,
            'call': transfer_call,
        },
    )

    nonce = substrate.get_account_nonce(keypair.ss58_address)
    signature_payload = substrate.generate_signature_payload(call=call, nonce=nonce)

    signature = keypair.sign(signature_payload)

    extrinsic = substrate.create_signed_extrinsic(
        call=call, keypair=keypair, signature=signature
    )

    print(extrinsic)

    result = substrate.submit_extrinsic(extrinsic=extrinsic, wait_for_finalization=False)
```

Also, the transaction is listed under the 'Extrinsics' tab in the explorer, rather than the 'Transfers' tab. Any advice on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is clearly visible here.

If this succeeds, it means you can transfer someone's money without their permission.

[image]

You must set up the proxy first. Use `proxy.add_proxy`.

Comment: Thanks, I realised it later yesterday evening. I was sending the tx as the stash account rather then from the Proxy.